# Error installing Maven Integration on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse-Helios. I need to install Maven Plugin on eclipse.

I am using following update URL:
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Missing requirement: Maven POM XML Editor 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml [1.4.0.20130601-0317]

Comment: Try to install it from the Eclipse Marketplace instead. `Help->Eclipse Marketplace` and search for *maven*.

Comment: For some reason, http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/ worked perfectly without any problem

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases given on their official site sometimes doesn't work, instead this works:

Go to Help -> Install New Software -> Add http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Comment: Please see my own comment below question :)

Comment: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3 this one saved my day thank you mate